# Table's updating after closing modal window in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have some `view`, which displaying some tabular data. I can add data, delete them and update. I make `CRUD` from modal window (`NoticeEdit.html`). I need to update the `view` (`Notices.html`) after each change. For example, after the removing records `view` is updated. But after adding - no, I need to refresh the entire page.

How can I update `view` when returning from modal window?

Relevant part of the AngularJS `view` (`Notices.html`):

```
<div 
    class="..."  
    ng-controller="NoticesCtrl">

<div class="..." >
   <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
         <table class="..." ng-model="noticesList">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>№</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th> ... </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="notice in noticesList">
                  <th>{{$index+1}}</th>
                  <th>{{notice.noticeDate}}</th>
                  <th>{{notice.noticeStatus}}</th>                        
                  <th>

                     <button class="..." ng-click="editNotice(notice.id)">Edit</button>
                     <button class="..." ng-click="deleteNotice(notice.id)">Remove</button>
                  </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

AngularJS controller (`Notices.js`):

```
function NoticesCtrl($scope, $http, $resource, $modal, Notices ) {
   $scope.noticesList = Notices.query();
   $scope.editNotice = function (idValue) {
           var modalInstance = $modal.open({
               templateUrl: 'views/Notices/NoticeEdit.html',
               controller: NoticeEditCtrl,
               resolve : { editId : function () { return idValue; } }
           });
   };

   $scope.deleteNotice = function (idValue) {
           var modalInstance = $modal.open({
               templateUrl: 'views/Notices/NoticeDelete.html',
               controller: NoticeEditCtrl,
               resolve : { editId : function () {
                    return idValue; }
               }
           });

           modalInstance.result.then(function () {
              $scope.loadNotices ();
           }, function () {});
   };

   $scope.loadNotices = function () {
        $scope.noticesList = Notices.query();
        $scope.$apply();
   }
}

NoticesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', '$modal','Notices'];
```

AngularJS controller (`NoticeEdit.js`):

```
function NoticeEditCtrl($scope, $http, $resource, $modalInstance, $moment, $window, Notices, editId ) {
    $scope.model = new Notices({id : 0});
    if (editId > 0) {
        Notices.get ({id : editId}, function (data) { $scope.model = data; })
    }

    $scope.noticeDate = new Date();
    $scope.noticeDateBegin = $moment().date(-30).hour(0).minute(0).toDate();
    $scope.noticeDateEnd = new Date();

    $scope.ok = function () {
        Notices.save ($scope.model, function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
            $window.location.reload();
        });
    };

    $scope.deleteOk = function () {
      if ($scope.model.id > 0) {
        Notices.delete ($scope.model, function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        });
      }
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

   $scope.loadNotices = function () {
        $scope.noticesList = Notices.query();
        $scope.$apply();
   }
}

NoticeEditCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', '$modalInstance', "$moment", "$window", 'Notices', 'editId'];
```

AngularJS factory (`Notices.js`):

```
function Notices($resource) {
    return $resource ('/api/notices/:id');
}
Notices.$inject = ['$resource'];
```

Relevant part of the Play 1.3 route (`routes.conf`)

```
POST    /api/notices      NoticeMessageController.update
```

Relevant part of the Play 1.3 controller (`update()` action):

```
public class NoticeMessageController extends Controller {
    public static void update() {
        Notice jsonNoticeMessage = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(request.params.get("body"), Notice.class);
        Notice notice = (jsonNoticeMessage.id > 0) ? (Notice) Notice.findById(jsonNoticeMessage.id) : new Notice();

        ...

        notice.save();
        renderJSON(notice);
    }
    ...
```

`NoticeEdit.html` is a modal window:

[image]

I'm doing `$window.location.reload();` but this is not what I need. I need to update only the table.

Comment: Do you mean for the refresh to happen after $scope.ok and $scope.deleteOk?

Comment: I think you just need a `$scope.$apply()` after `$modalInstance.close();`

Comment: sorry, just realized I was looking at the modal controller, so I think that's the wrong $scope to $apply().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try, inside `Notices.js`:

```
       modalInstance.result.then(function () {
          $scope.loadNotices ();
          $scope.$apply();
       }, function () {});
```

I'd guess that what's happening is you're expecting the automatic watch on `$scope.noticesList` to result in a view update after `Notices.save()` and `Notices.delete()` happen in the modal controller. Unless you explicitly create a watch with `objectEquality === true`, though, variables are only watched shallowly. A property change inside a shallowly-watched object doesn't register a change; only replacing it with a different object would.

If this doesn't work, you may want to create an explicit watch on `noticesList`:

```
$scope.$watch('noticesList', someFunction, true);
```

I'm 98% sure this would detect a change when you delete a `Notice`, but if it doesn't detect a change within a specific `Notice`, you may need to use `$watchCollection`, or even `$watch` a function that includes `JSON.stringify()`.